# How to ignore * when processing a a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, glob

This is my file:

```
cat abx.txt

select * from table1;
select * from table2;
select * from table3;

yu=$(head -1 abx.txt)
echo $yu
```

=> select file1.txt file2.txt from table

How can I avoid the processing of `*` when assigning to a variable. I have already added `\*` but the variable has the value `\*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename expansion is happening when you echo `$yu`. You simply need to surround the variable with double quotes to prevent it:

```
$ yu=$(head -1 abx.txt)
$ echo "$yu"
select * from table1;
```